# KeyValueTextInputFormat in Driver class

Tags: java, mapreduce

In new API (apache.hadoop.mapreduce.KeyValueTextInputFormat) , how to specify separator (delimiter) other than tab(which is default) to separate key and Value.

Sample Input :
    106298345|Surender,Raja,CTS,50000,Chennai
    106297845|Murali,Bala,TCS,60000,Chennai
    106291271|Rajagopal,Ravi,CTS,50000,Chennai
    106298616|Vikram,Darma,TCS,70000,Chennai
    106299100|Kumar,Selvam,TCS,90000,Chennai
    106299288|Sandeep,Krishna,CTS,10000,Chennai
    106290071|Vimal,Pillai,TCS,20000,Chennai

I am specifying KeyValueTextInputFormat as :

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator", "|");
Job myhadoopJob = new Job(conf);
```

my mapper code is below

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;

public class KeyValueMapper extends  Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text>
{
@Override
protected void map(Text key, Text value, Context context)throws IOException,       InterruptedException {
String mapOutPutValue="";
String line = value.toString();
String[] details=line.split(",");
for(int i=0;i<details.length;i++)
{
if(details[i].equalsIgnoreCase("TCS"))
{
mapOutPutValue=line;
}
}if(mapOutPutValue!="")context.write(key, new Text(mapOutPutValue)); }

}
```

but my mapper class is printing all the output in my inputfile.My mapper class is not filtering the  input as per logic in map method..

Can Someone help me

Comment: myhadoopJob.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
  myhadoopJob.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below option in driver code.

`conf.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", "|");`

Comment: Its okay. No problem.